# Using views in BigQuery vs actual table

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a usecase where we are storing sales by products  in a BigQuery table. This table has the records at a order-product level. Our organization uses a fiscal calendar which is from February to January. We have a fiscal calendar table which provides all the details given a date.

Instead of having users query this order-product table and the fiscal calendar table and deriving the This Year and Last year Fiscal week details we wanted to have these fiscal weeks embedded into the order-product table.

We can do it 2 ways:

1. Create a view which sits on the order-product and the fiscal calendar table and expose this view for querying
2. Change the process which loads the order-product table and get the fiscal dates into the physical table

I wanted to know which of the above is a better approach. If there is any other approach which is not listed above and is more efficient then I am open to knowing them as well.

The order-product table is partitioned on order-date and has about 100 - 120 million records overall for the last 4 years.

Comment: Sql Server has offset feature where you can “page” through results.. You could try to emulate it by getting a number of this or last (reverse) year’s orders since they come in chronologically.. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Better approach as to what? performance? costs? elegance of the solution?